# How can I access ads data to a specific account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I have an approved developer token from google that belongs to a production manager account.

Now as far as I understood I need the `customerId` and a `refreshtoken`
in order to access the ads data.

So my config file looks like:

```
'test'    => [
    'developerToken'   => "ZaFVf123123LHvelJFcycmjQ",
    'clientCustomerId' => "123-123-6335",
    'userAgent'        => "Test-Account",
    'clientId'         => "1212312315-tkim0s5dh0s2p1iu12312312c5eau.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    'clientSecret'     => "7123123P0JaDMYgKBhl3vLI",
    'refreshToken'     => "1/D1233wN9oBwg-0Ih837hplOuuEhAEkOPmzg7PbBRZs",
],
```

Could someone clarify how the authentication it should happen? My current understanding is:

1. I create a google web app and get client id and secret from there.
2. I have a developer token that belongs to a production account.
3. I need a clientCustumerID in order to read the ads data for that specific account
4. In order to read the data should I get the refresh token from manager account or from the account that I am trying to read the data from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I create a google web app and get client id and secret from there.

You create a project on google developer console which is identified by the client id and secret.  It will be used to request access to private user data.

> I have a developer token that belongs to a production account.

I am not sure i understand what you mean by developer token.

> I need a clientCustumerID in order to read the ads data for that specific account.

Yes it can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#client_customer_id)

> In order to read the data should I get the refresh token from manager account or from the account that I am trying to read the data from ?

In order to read the data you will need an access token.  The access token can then be used to access the data.  The access token is only valid for one hour then it will expire you can then use your refresh token to gain a new access token.  Most libraries handle this for you.

This link may help [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call)

Comment: well based on google documentation, I must have either a test manager account or production manager account to access the users ads connected to that manager account! In order to make calls I need a token so I applied for basic token and waited until google approved it! So now I got it. So in order to to read ads for a specific customer I need to get a refresh token or get the user authorization using my google app client id and secret ? btw google docs are like a deep black hole in space.

Comment: deep black hole in space  <--- agreed